# Cryptic Riddle!

Tags: riddle, word

> I am  a 6 letter word.
>   I am a part of your daily life.
>   Remove the third letter from me and if you leave enough space, i am available.
>   Remove the last letter from me and read me backwards,avid readers will easily identify me.
>   Shuffle me, even if it feels good, I would just say not bad.

Who am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> a **TOILET**
>
>  Definitely part of our daily lives.
>  Removing third letter and inserting a **space** gives "TO LET" - available to rent
>  Removing the last letter and reading backwards gives ELIOT, as in T. S. Eliot
>  Shuffling the letters around gives LITOTE, which (while properly spelled "litotes", even when singular) describes an understated way of expressing a (usually negative) idea.

Comment: Litote is the anagram.

Comment: That's...not really a word. It's "litotes" for both singular and plural.  But thank you.